# bash script to run command-line java program

Tags: java, bash

Currently I run my program like this:

```
java program arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

There are a variable number or arguments. Is there some BASH script or something I can package with my program to allow me to run it just like

```
program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and continue to allow me to have variable arguments.

I just care about Unix systems.

I'm sorry for this simple question: I'm a Java developer, not a BASH scriptor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
#!/bin/bash

java program "$@"
```

Or if you want the bash to exit when java is called, use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec java program "$@"
```

(This replaces the `bash` process with the `java` process instead of waiting until `java` returns.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use an alias:

```
alias program='java program'
```

Comment: Since he wants to pass arguments, I doubt aliases can be used. A function would be needed.

Comment: @qwerty Arguments very much can be used with aliases. Try it yourself.

Comment: Common way of doing it, is using a batch file.

Comment: @gyger The OP is using bash in Unix. Batch files are for Windows.